# Hypernym for acronym, abbreviation, and symbol

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

What would the hypernym of *acronym*, *abbreviation*, and *symbol* be? I know that abbreviation is a hypernym for Initialism and Acronym, but is there a word that includes abbreviation and symbols, I'm referring to mathematical symbols mostly. Somthing like *x*<sub>min</sub> instead of the longer term: The minimum value of *x*.

The reason I think such a word might exist is because there is some amount of overlap between the terms: They are all a set of terms that can be used to shorten and simplify a more difficult to read term.

It is for the name of a chapter that lists all the above used in a thesis, and I did not think glossary *quite* covered it.

### Edit

The word will be combined with *Nomenclature* in the title, i.e. “*Hypernym* and Nomenclature”. Previously this question asked for a Hypernym of all of *acronym*, *abbreviation*, *symbols* and *nomenclature*. However, it was pointed out that this question was too broad, and the inclusion of nomenclature probably made it impossible to answer, that there was little overlap between the nomenclature and the other three terms.

Comment: "Glossary" is probably the best you can do for your list.  It's not a "hypernym", but it basically means "list of terms", and "terms" is about as close to a hypernym as you'll get.

Comment: Terms, and glossary as a collection of terms, is probably the best suggestion thus far. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If we are talking about definitions rather than, say, a linguistic distinction between initialisms and acronyms, then why isn't "nomenclature" the hypernym?

Comment: [Shorthand](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/shorthand) comes quite close, but I won't propose it as an actual answer because I think it's a just word for a method of writing which employs those things, rather than a hypernym for whatever they are. However, I think it goes to show that these are closely related enough that a word like this might exist and you might do well to include a definition of the term in your question to further strengthen the relationship, and encourage people to actually check, esp. if they have a background *in* using various forms of shorthand.

Comment: Perhaps you could call it ***Terminology***

Comment: Uh… thanks, Tonepoet and d'you think that use of *shorthand* could be rather tenuous, even if it did *employ those things*.

Jim's *terminology* could include *nomenclature* and - just *acronym; abbreviation* but hardly *symbol* and either way it's little more specific than *words* or *language*.

Please look back and see *They are all a set of terms that can be used to shorten and simplify a more difficult to read term* isn't true because that doesn't even approach, let alone describe, *nomenclature*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a hypernym for almost certainly non-comparable terms.

Comment: Surely it's not *off topic*, just *not answerable*. Which is itself an answer, just an unsatisfying one.

Comment: I agree that the terms are dificult to compare. Nomenclature throws a spanner in the works as it describes as *system* and *convention* of naming. Where as the others describe a stand-in for a longer (usually by number of characters) or more complicated term. In which case, something like *(Hypernym for acronym, abbreviation, and symbol) and nomenclature* might be the best answer.

Comment: Uh, they're all "symbols".  As are all the letters in this comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We already discussed the matter of how to handle S.W.Rs. that don't have a matching word. The general consensus was not to close them for being off-topic, but [rather that no can be a valid answer.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/how-should-we-handle-single-word-requests-that-dont-have-a-matching-word/4351#4351) I'm just not satisfied that it is in this case for reasons I already mentioned, but if you can provide adequate proof that this is the case, then perhaps an answer to that effect is in order.

Comment: @Tonepoet It's incredibly difficult to prove a negative. With the original question, there remained a slight chance that an obscure word with different senses with meanings close enough to both 'abbreviation' and 'nomenclature' to work as a fudge could exist. But it would be a fudge; I wouldn't say that 'cap' is a hypernym for 'peaked hat' and 'ceiling'. It's a synonym of each individually. // The dropping of 'nomenclature' and well-defining of 'symbol'  makes the question much better, though 'shortened form' now seems the trivial answer.

Answer (score 0):

An acronym is a kind of abbreviation. A symbol and abbreviation are both representations or short forms (one an image the other still text) of the original. Nomenclature is an alternate form, but not necessarily short.

There is some overlap between the terms, but there is some that is not. Finding the right word here might be a case of looking at what you are excluding rather than including. If you are referring only to shortened words, the 'shortened forms' (or 'short forms') is probably the most fitting.

Otherwise, going the other way and being broad enough to cover everything, 'alternate forms' or 'terminology' may work.

Comment: Hello. anon. I'd missed this question; I think the only correct course of action is to close-vote; the inclusion of 'nomenclature' seems only just short of the inclusion of 'noun'. Robbie Goodwin pointed out the almost certain  non-availability of an answer here. Doing it using different words doesn't add much.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to point this out but it's not that 'glossary' doesn't *quite* cover it. 'Glossary' doesn't *begin to* cover it and nothing else could, either.

Please reconsider the meanings of acronym, abbreviation, nomenclature, and symbol, how they overlap and how they differ. Within their overlap they might in theory share a hypernym but how otherwise? If all four terms were broadly synonymous there might be a case; else, not.

To what extend are all four terms even synonymous, please?

What difference did you think it would make whether you had a chapter in need of a name or a list looking for members or whether either or both was to be used in a thesis, or otherwise?

Comment: Acronym, abbreviation, nomenclature, and symbol all represent broadly a set of (usually shorter) terms that are used in place of a more difficult to read or longer word or phrase. They are not synonymous, but they are related and do overlap. Nothing is synonymous if you approach it with sufficiently fine detail or from a narrow technical perspective.

A single word or simple phrase would suit a chapter title better than a longer phrase or sentence. A longer name (perhaps with an acronym, abbreviation or symbol to refer to them quickly… ) would be ok if refering to the set.

Comment: I'm voting against this answer because while it is not a word *for* this as far as I know, the word [shorthand](http://www.finedictionary.com/shorthand.html) puts a hole in your rationale by suggesting that these are more closely related than you suggest, which as of yet is your sole rationale for suggesting the word doesn't exist. If you can come up with a more persuasive rationale to *edit into the answer*, please ping me so I can consider retracting the vote.

Comment: That definition I provided above where symbols are just pictured is different from the one I provide down here, where symbols are = mentioned by name. The discrepancy is because of a different revision of the dictionary [after checking against website with another set of scans from the C.D.C's. 1914 printing.](http://www.global-language.com/century/). Symbols are mentioned by name there, albeit not expressly nomenclature. Perhaps you could use that to your advantage to suggest that it is unreasonable to have a word for *all four* in an edit, but the gist of the request still seems reasonable.

Comment: @tmgriffiths No; _nomenclature_ is far broader. [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nomenclature)  has the very general << the terminology used in a particular science, art, activity, etc >>. The others (with the more precise definition of 'symbol' OP has now added) overlap to a far greater degree.